# 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http' does not have a strong name

Tags: class-library, strongname, asp.net-core

### Update 2015-11-17

It seems that vNext assemblies (Microsoft.AspNet) are now signed (have strong names).

Check the following thread on GitHub:

[Assemblies are now strong named #109](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/109)

---

I want to create a digital signed assembly, which will use types implemented in one of the vNext assemblies. At this moment, vNext assemblies do not have a strong name attribute. As a result, the following error occurs while building a solution:

**"Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http' does not have a strong name"**

Is this behavior a known issue (for example, related to the VS2015 CTP)? Is it going to be changed in the future? What is the recommended way to proceed?

Comment: Though I answered a specific question below, it might be helpful to understand why you want to strong-name sign a DLL to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update 2015-11-17

As noted by Mikhail, nearly all the assemblies that are part of DNX 1, ASP.NET 5, and EF 7 have strong-name signatures.

They all use a private key that is *checked in* to the repo, so anyone can build the same DLLs with the same strong-name key. No "delay sign" or "test sign" process.

---

### Original post 2015-02-11

There are no current plans to strong-name sign all the DLLs in ASP.NET 5. (Source: I work on the project.)

And because strong-name are "viral" (a strong-name signed assembly must reference only other strong-name signed assemblies), that means you cannot strong-name any assembly that depends on ASP.NET 5.

Comment: I am going to port existing signed assemblies with ASP.NET components to the vNext environment. For this purpose, I am creating a new assembly that references my existing assemblies and uses types implemented in one of the vNext assemblies. As a result, I will have to sign the newly created assembly and the referenced vNext one.
Am I allowed to do it from the EULA perspective (i.e., creating and distributing my built and signed version of any vNext assembly)? What is the recommended way to accomplish my task?

Comment: If you build from the source code, it's plain old Apache 2.0, which lets you do almost anything you want with the code. And to add a strong name, you have to recompile anyway to put the public key in. Having said that, we're looking into the possibility of putting some arbitrary strong name on the assemblies to help out people in your situation. I don't personally recommend adding a strong name to a DLL you don't own because that changes its identity, and that means that anyone else trying to use the DLL won't work either.

Comment: It seems that vNext assemblies (Microsoft.AspNet) are now signed (have strong names). Check the following thread on GitHub:
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/109
I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: @Mikhail thanks, I updated my answer to reflect this.